# How do modern implementations of Comet/Reverse AJAX work? Any stable C# WCF or ASP.NET implementations?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, comet, push-notification, reverse-ajax

What is the correct way (or best) way to implement Comet, HTTP Push, or Reverse AJAX?

What .NET implementations would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have hear about, [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/) and [PokeIn](http://pokein.com/), both are paid implementations, I have used PokeIn and its pretty straight forward. If you are looking forward to code your own COMET implementation, I just can say that its a complex task, because you need to modify the natural behaviour if IIS. Its a hacky way to get around the limitations of the HTTP protocol and you need to know really well what you doing so don't end up breaking things around =).

> It's also known as long-lived
>   requests. This is also by far the most
>   complex method to implement.
>   Basically, a request is made by the
>   client, and the server *very* slowly
>   responds, which causes the connection
>   to be maintained. Periodically, when
>   the server has something to push,
>   it'll "burst" send the information, so
>   to speak. This approach gives you
>   real-time push, which is great. But,
>   it has a serious down-side: holding
>   connections open like that isn't how
>   the underlying protocols are meant to
>   work, and most servers aren't terribly
>   happy about it. If your traffic gets
>   too great, you'll chew up threads on
>   the server and wind up bringing your
>   site down.
>   ref: http://www.coderanch.com/t/121668/HTML-JavaScript/does-Reverse-Ajax-Works

Comment: What do you think of using Silverlight's HTTP Push technology as a bridge to Javascript as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449642/http-push-comet-reverse-ajaxusing-silverlight-to-javascript-bridge

Comment: I have no experience with silverlight, checkout this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640488/silverlight-and-push-notifications, if those are included as part of Silverlight SDK, then it should be safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

JOBG is correct re: the complexities; it's probably not a task you want to undertake lightly. I'm one of the authors of [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), and I can attest that it's a difficult task.

There are a ton of examples in the download, and the community edition is free.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is developing HTTP push in SignalR

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR