# HTTP-Push (Comet/Reverse Ajax)using Silverlight to Javascript bridge?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, comet, pollingduplexhttpbinding

Is it a good idea to use [PollingDuplexHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.pollingduplexhttpbinding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) [with Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640488/silverlight-and-push-notifications) in conjunction with the function `RegisterScriptableObject` to achieve Comet-style javascript functionality?
 ([see tutorial](http://michaelsync.net/2008/01/18/silverlight-tipstricks-communicating-between-javascript-and-c))

I have never seen this approach discussed in the forums, or recommended as a free solution.  Instead only heard about paid options such as [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/) and [PokeIn](http://pokein.com/).

Does Silverlight implement the [the Bayeux protocol](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html)?  Should it?

Comment: I found an alternative... .SignalR by Microsoft: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have some serious scalability problems, and it's a royal pain to implement. See:

http://devgripes.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/pollingduplexhttpbinding-absolute-rubbish/

If you want a Bayeux implementation in Silverlight, you want WebSync.

(Disclaimer: I work for Frozen Mountain Software)