# Is it possible to create a push application using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am confused how I would refresh the HTTP sessions on the client side whenever the data is updated on the server side.  I am using ASP.net with C# and SQL Server DB. I don't want to implement a timer on the client side and want to push notifications from server side.

Just want to know if its possible and a high level understanding of it will be enough.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP, by definition, was not designed to "PUSH"... rather, it is designed, from the ground-up to PULL or POLL changes.

One of the major reasons for this is the ability to massively scale via caching on multiple levels (content storage level, web server level, proxy server level, client level, etc.)

To create a system where you PUSH changes, you'll have to resort to TCP/IP.

**But, you do have a couple options for this:**

- Flash (Cross-Browser, Cross-Platform, Widely Supported, Requires Plugin)
- Silverlight (Cross-Browser, Mac/PC, Less Supported than Flash, Requires Plugin)
- ActiveX (IE, PC, Requires special permissions most times)

Can all be used to create a connection with the service and wait for updates to be pushed.

Emerging Options:

- WebSockets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets (Only supported in uber-modern browsers, not completely standardized yet)

Comment: Great answer. I want to use Silverlight for the client side. If I use Silverlight that retrieves data from the server side asp.net application then instead of polling every second on silverlight end, how would you suggest I should implement pushing data to silverlight front end?

Comment: There is a great answer on specifically that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640488/silverlight-and-push-notifications    *If* you like my answer, would you be so kind as to upvote it and click the little check mark next to it, marking it as the answer : ) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) solution like [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/).

Take a look at this answer's to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net).